# Dudley's Inequality can be Loose (Vershynin 8.1.12)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, concentration-of-measure

Let $e_1,...,e_n$ denote the canonical basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the set
$$T = \left \{ \frac{e_k}{\sqrt{1 + \log k}}, k =1,...,n\right \}$$
Show that
$$\int_{0}^\infty \sqrt{\log \mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)} d\epsilon \rightarrow\infty$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Here $\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)$ is the size of the smallest $\epsilon$-net of $T$ with respect to the metric $d$.

An $\epsilon$-net in this context is a set $N \subset T$ such that for all $t \in T$ there is an $s \in N$ such that $d(s,t) \leq \epsilon$.

I assume that $d(x,y) = ||x-y||_2$, although this isn't explicitly stated. Also note,that $\epsilon$-nets must be  subsets of $T$

I also write $\log$ when really I mean $\ln$.

---

I've spent quite a bit of time working on this exercise and from what I can tell, unless I've missed the trick completely, is that this example actually does not work. Here is my argument.

For convenience, let $v_k = \frac{e_k}{\sqrt{1+\log k}}$.

Let $f_n(k):\{1,...,n-1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be defined as
$$f_n(k) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\log k} + \frac{1}{1+\log n}}$$
It is easy to see that for $1 \leq j < k \leq n$ we have
$$||v_j -v_k||_2 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\log j}+\frac{1}{1+\log k}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\log j}+\frac{1}{1+\log n}} = ||v_j - v_n||_2 =f_n(j)$$
Now let $1 \leq k \leq n-2$ and let $\epsilon \in [f_n(k+1),f_n(k))$. Let $N$ be an $\epsilon$-net of $T$. It must be that for all $j \leq k$ that $v_j \in N$ since the nearest point
$$\min_{i \neq j} ||v_j - v_i||_2 = ||v_j - v_n|| = f_n(j) \geq f_n(k) > \epsilon.$$
Therefore $|N| \geq k+1$ since $\{v_1,...,v_k\} \subset N$ and we need at least one more point for $v_n$.
Also note that $N = \{v_1,...,v_k,v_n\}$ is an $\epsilon$-net since for all $j \geq k+1$ we have
$$||v_j - v_n||_2 = f_n(j) \leq f_n(k+1) \leq \epsilon.$$
This and the lower bound shows that $N$ is best possible and therefore that $\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon) = k+1$.

Also note that for $\epsilon < f_n(n-1)$ the only possible $\epsilon$-net is $T$ and therefore $\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon) = |T| = n$ for $\epsilon < f_n(n-1)$. Similarly for $\epsilon \geq f_n(1)$ the set $N = v_n$ is an $\epsilon$-net.

We next put these bounds on $\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)$ together. First we can use what happens when $\epsilon \geq f_n(1)$.
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log \mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)}d\epsilon &= \int_0^{f_n(1)} \sqrt{\log \mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)}d\epsilon + \int_{f_n(1)}^\infty \sqrt{\log \mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)}d\epsilon \\
&= \int_0^{f_n(1)} \sqrt{\log \mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)}d\epsilon + \int_{f_n(1)}^\infty \sqrt{\log 1}d\epsilon \\
&= \int_0^{f_n(1)} \sqrt{\log \mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)}d\epsilon
\end{align}
Next we split the integral up
\begin{align}
\int_0^{f_n(1)} \sqrt{\log \mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)}d\epsilon &= \int_0^{f_n(n-1)} \sqrt{\log \mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)}d\epsilon + \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} \int_{f_n(i+1)}^{f_n(i)} \sqrt{\log \mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)}d\epsilon \\
&= \int_0^{f_n(n-1)} \sqrt{\log(n)}d\epsilon + \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} \int_{f_n(i+1)}^{f_n(i)} \sqrt{\log(i+1)}d\epsilon \\
&= f_n(n-1)\sqrt{\log n} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} [f_n(i) - f_n(i+1)]\sqrt{\log(i+1)}
\end{align}
So far this is all an exact equality. If we substitute in the definition of $f_n$ into this expression we get
$$\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{1+\log (n-1)} + \frac{\log n}{1+\log n}} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\sqrt{\frac{\log(i+1)}{1+\log i } + \frac{\log(i+1)}{1+\log n}}-\sqrt{\frac{\log(i+1)}{1+\log(i+1)} + \frac{\log(i+1)}{1+\log n}}$$
Numerically however this seems to converge to less than 3. So either the series grows incredibly slowly or it is failing to grow to infinity.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, if you try replacing $||\cdot||_2$ with $||\cdot||_1$ it doesn't appear to help

Comment: Jesus, that last thing u get looks painful to estimate (i tried for a bit). It is possible it grows like $\log \log n$. It takes a long time for $\log\log n$ to exceed $3$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long think I've also come to what I feel is the cleanest solution to this problem so far.

It starts with Lemma 4.2.8, which stats for any set $T$ that
$$\mathcal{P}(T,2\varepsilon) \leq \mathcal{N}(T,\varepsilon) \leq \mathcal{P}(T,\varepsilon).$$
The lower bound is the one of interest. Plugging this into Dudley's integral gives
\begin{align}
   \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log(\mathcal{N}(T,\varepsilon))} d\varepsilon 
   &\geq \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log(\mathcal{P}(T,2\varepsilon))} d\varepsilon \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log(\mathcal{P}(T,\varepsilon))} d\varepsilon
\end{align}
Now we can lower bound $\mathcal{P}(T,\varepsilon)$ in the following way. Recall the definition
$$v_k = \frac{e_k}{\sqrt{1+\log(k)}}$$
and therefore for $k > j \geq 1$ we have
\begin{align}
    \|v_j - v_k\|_2 &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\log(j)} + \frac{1}{1+\log(k)}} \\
    &> \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\log(k)} + \frac{1}{1+\log(k)}} &(k > j)\\
    &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\log(k)}}
\end{align}
Now set this equal to $\varepsilon$ and solve
\begin{align}
    \varepsilon = \sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\log(k)}} \iff k= \exp\left ( \frac{2}{\varepsilon^2} -1\right )
\end{align}
In particular this shows that with $k(\varepsilon) = \left \lfloor \exp\left ( \frac{2}{\varepsilon^2} -1\right )\right \rfloor$ that $v_1,...,v_{k(\varepsilon)}$ are $\epsilon$ separated. This establishes
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{P}(T,\varepsilon) \geq k(\varepsilon) = \left \lfloor \exp\left ( \frac{2}{\varepsilon^2} -1\right )\right \rfloor
\end{equation}
To clean up some of the calculations I will use the bound, valid for all $\varepsilon \leq 1/2$
$$\left \lfloor \exp\left ( \frac{2}{\varepsilon^2} -1\right )\right \rfloor \geq \exp\left( \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \right).$$
I'll prove this at the end. Using the bounds we have shown above we have
\begin{align}
 \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log(\mathcal{P}(T,\varepsilon))} d\varepsilon
 &\geq \int_0^{1/2} \sqrt{\log(\mathcal{P}(T,\varepsilon))} d\varepsilon \\
 &\geq \int_0^{1/2} \sqrt{\log(k(\varepsilon))} d\varepsilon \\
 &\geq \int_0^{1/2} \sqrt{\log(e^{1/\varepsilon^2})} d\varepsilon \\
 &= \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} d\varepsilon = +\infty.
\end{align}
which shows the result.

---

Here's the proof of the inequality. For $\varepsilon \leq 1/2$ we have
\begin{align}
   \left \lfloor \exp\left( \frac{2}{\varepsilon^2} - 1 \right ) \right \rfloor 
   &\geq \left \lfloor \exp\left( \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} + \frac{1}{(1/2)^2} - 1\right ) \right \rfloor \\
   &=  \left \lfloor \exp\left( \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \right ) \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor e^{3} \exp\left( \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \right ) \right \rfloor
\end{align}
To conclude note that $\exp\left( \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \right ) \geq e^4 > 1$ and $e^3 > 2$ and use the inequality valid for all $a > 1, b > 2$
$$\lfloor ba \rfloor \geq a.$$

---

I really appreciate the high quality answers from ExcitedMathematician and user140541! Both inspired me to find this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using the hint on p.269, (the first $m$ vectors in $T$ form a $ 1/\sqrt{\ln(m)}$-separated set), let $v_m:= 1/\sqrt{\ln(em)}$, and $u_n:=\ln(n)/\ln(en)$. Then, assuming that $n\ge 3$,
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\sqrt{\ln \mathcal{N}(T,d,\varepsilon)}\,d\varepsilon&\ge  \int_0^{v_{n}}\sqrt{\ln n}\,d\varepsilon +\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} \int_{v_{n-i+1}}^{v_{n-i}}\sqrt{\ln(n-i)}\,d\varepsilon \\
&=\sqrt{u_n}+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ln(i)}{\ln(ei)}}-\sqrt{\frac{\ln(i)}{\ln(e(i+1))}}\right) \\
&\ge \sqrt{u_n}+\int_2^{n-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(ex)}}-\sqrt{\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(e(x+1))}}\right)dx \\
&\ge \sqrt{u_n}+\int_2^{n-1}\frac{1}{e(x+1)\ln(e(x+1))}\,dx \\
&\ge e^{-1}\ln(\ln(n))\to\infty
\end{align}
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Consider for example $m = 10, n=10,000$ then the covering number for $\epsilon = 1/\sqrt{\log 10}$ of $\{v_1,...,v_{10}\}$ is $10$, but for $\{v_1,...,v_{10},v_{10,000}\}$ it is only 8. I believe this breaks your argument.

Comment: What are $v_1,\ldots,v_{10000}$?

Comment: In the original post they are defined by $v_i = \frac{e_i}{\sqrt{1 + \log i}}$ where $e_i$ is the $i$'th standard basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You're right. I missed the "1+" term. It becomes even worse as $n$ grows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{\log{N(T,\epsilon)}} = \int_{0}^{diam(T)} \sqrt{\log{N(T,\epsilon)}}$$

Make the change of variables $\epsilon = 2/\sqrt{\log{t}}$ and define $diam(T)=d(T)$. Then

$$\int_{0}^{diam(T)} \sqrt{\log{N(T,\epsilon)}} d\epsilon = \int_{e^{4/d(T)^{2}}}^{\infty} \sqrt{\log{N(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\log{t}}})}} \frac{dt}{t (\log{t})^{3/2}} \geq \int_{e^{4/d(T)^{2}}}^{\infty} \sqrt{\log{P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log{t}}})}} \frac{dt}{t (\log{t})^{3/2}}$$

Where $P$ is the packing number. Now, note that it is a decreasing function of it's argument so

$$\int_{0}^{diam(T)} \sqrt{\log{N(T,\epsilon)}} d\epsilon \geq \sum_{m = \lceil e^{4/d(T)^{2}}\rceil}^{\infty} \int_{m}^{m + 1}\frac{\sqrt{\log{m}}}{t (\log{t})^{3/2}}dt \geq \sum_{m = \lceil e^{4/d(T)^{2}}\rceil}^{\infty} \int_{m}^{m + 1}\frac{(\log{m})^{1/2}}{(m+1)(\log{(m+1)})^{3/2}}dt$$

Moreover
$$\int_{0}^{diam(T)} \sqrt{\log{N(T,\epsilon)}} d\epsilon \geq \sum_{m = \lceil e^{4/d(T)^{2}}\rceil}^{\infty} \frac{(\log{m})^{1/2}}{(m+1)(\log{(m+1)})^{3/2}} \to \sum_{m \geq 2} \frac{(\log{m})^{1/2}}{(m+1)(\log{(m+1)})^{3/2}} \geq  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m \geq 2}\frac{(\log{m})^{1/2}}{m(\log{(m+1)})^{3/2}}$$

Where the limit holds. Now we apply a Cauchy's condensation test to show it diverges

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m \geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{m} \sqrt{\log{2}}}{(\log{(2^{m} +1)})^{3/2}} \geq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m \geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{m} \sqrt{\log{2}}}{(\log{(2^{2m})})^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m \geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{m} \sqrt{\log{2}}}{(2)^{3/2}m^{3/2}} \propto \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m}$$

This is a multiple of the harmonic series so it diverges! (I believe it should probably apply to your last series)

As a result

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{\log{N(T,\epsilon)}} \to \infty $$